# pair of K, low kicker, out of position

Tags: hand-history

I had this situation (fake money, very low buy in):

[image]

I folded because I was afraid of two A.

- Was it correct to play at blinds A5o?
- What should I have done at the flop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Middle pair with no kicker against a several opponents is a very weak hand. Add in that you are out of position and that the higher card is an Ace (which is the most likely card for people to hold onto), and this is an easy fold on the flop.

I don't understand your question about playing at the blinds. The way the hand looks, you were in the big blind, so you had no choice about whether or not to play this hand preflop. If that is incorrect, you definitely should not have called preflop with K5 offsuit from early position. It is took weak of a hand. Further if you get any action when you make your hand, it means that someone else has a stronger hand - often another K with a better kicker.

Comment: He's in the big blind, the big blind is 30 chips, there are 5 people in the hand, 150 chips pot on the flop. This means he checked preflop, didn't call or raise. You are right about the fact that someone may have an Ace or a King with a better kicker... But he said it was fake money he played with. When it comes to fake money, people play all kinds of garbage hands, including his opponents at that table... So he might just have the best hand... that's why I suggested a raise in my answer. If he meets resistance, he can just back off with minimal losses.

Comment: (I made a little bit of confusion on pre flop check/call). Probably with fake money SoboLAN answere is as good as this, but I choose this one since it gives more in depth and more general explanation. Thanks to both :)

Comment: @SoboLAN that's why I said that I didn't understand the question about "was it correct to play the blinds." There was no choice made, so that was where my question came in. Also, he said that it was fake money but a low buyin. To me, that doesn't mean play money; that means a low buyin tournament.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to any poker question is "it depends". What I mean by this is that you saw how your opponents played and when and how they bluffed etc. We don't have that information.

If I was you in that situation... I would've raised to about 80 - 100 and see what happens **. All the players are still in the hand, so there's a higher chance that one of them has an Ace. But you're chip leader...

** = Given the fact that you're playing with fake money... you'll most likely get called more than normally.... unfortunately.